# Функция которая открывает txt файл, читает и форматирует файл построчно в установленном формате

Tags: php, функции

Из данного файла txt нужно взять данные

DT1617T2, Problem Solving for Programming , Gordon MacIntyre  , 08/04/2016

12345678, 56

34567822, 67

12324654, 98

Должно получиться

File name : ppGM.txt

Module Code : DT1617T2

Module Title : Problem Solving for Programming

Tutor : Gordon MacIntyre

Marked date : 08/04/2016

12345678 : 56

34567822 : 67

12324654 : 98

А у меня получается

DT1617T2 Problem Solving for Programming Gordon MacIntyre 08/04/2016

12345678 56

34567822 67

12324654 98

Нуждаюсь в помощи, php пишу первый раз.

```
    function readLineByLine () {
        if (file_exists('ppGM.txt')){
            $tmaFileToOpen = fopen("ppGM.txt", "r"); // open our ppGM.txt file
            if ($tmaFileToOpen) { // true if no errors occured 
                while(!feof($tmaFileToOpen)) {
                    // variable $result will display data in line by line
                    $result = fgets($tmaFileToOpen, 1024);
                    $split = explode(',', $result);
                    echo '<p>' . $split[0] . $split[1] . $split[2] . $split[3] . '</p>';
                }
            } else { // if an error occured message will be displayed
                echo '<p>There is an error openning file!</p>';
            }
            fclose($tmaFileToOpen); // Close our ppGM.txt file 
        } else { // if file doesn't exist message will be displayed
            echo '<p>File requested not found!</p>';
        }
    }
        echo readLineByLine();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуйте такой код:

```
<?php

function readLineByLine () {
    $file_str = 'php.txt';
    if (file_exists($file_str)){

        $file = file($file_str);
        $named = explode(',', $file[0]);

        print 'File name: ' . basename($file_str) . '<br>';
        print 'Module Code: ' . $named[0] . '<br>';
        print 'Module Title: ' . $named[1] . '<br>';
        print 'Tutor: ' . $named[2] . '<br>';
        print 'Marked date: ' . $named[3] . '<br>';

        $len = count($file);

        for ($i=1; $i < $len; $i++) { 
            $str = explode(',', $file[$i]);
            print $str[0] . ': ' . $str[1] . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
readLineByLine();
```

**Выхлоп**

```
File name: php.txt
Module Code: DT1617T2
Module Title: Problem Solving for Programming
Tutor: Gordon MacIntyre
Marked date: 08/04/2016
12345678: 56
34567822: 67
12324654: 98
```